# How to retrieve contact by email with google api. PHP

Tags: php, search, oauth, google-api, contacts

I'm retrieving contacts with

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/(optional contactId)

But I need to fetch contacts by email instead of id.

Is there a way to to this? I have tried to solve this problem for a time now and can't find any help in the documentation..

I have been searching for an answer here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you have the answer already but in case your still looking :

```
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Query('http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?q='.$Number);
```

where `$Number` can be any part of the contact (email , address or phone number )