# Get all details of google contact via google contacts api

Tags: .net, google-api, google-contacts-api

I am able to query my google contacts via google contacts api using .net packages.
The query:

Feed f = cr.GetContacts();

Ofcourse after auth process.
The problem i have its that i cant find many details that i can see in my gmail, like: Notes,EmailAddress,Birthday,Anniversary,Company.

Ideally I would like my query to return the exact same values like the 'export contacts to csv' option in the web form in gmail.
The scope i am using:
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/
thanks.

Comment: You can get all the details of contacts with the contacts API. You have to send query for this. Check this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032305/how-to-retrieve-contact-by-email-with-google-api-php

Comment: I am able to get info, I just dont know where in the feed I am getting as a result,I can the find the fields i stated,i want to know how can i get all of my contacts and all of their info, just like in the export function in gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to stipulate **v=3.0 in your URL**, so that is can display all the information... For me it was all the information such as birthdays, anniversaries, etc.

Comment: I am using the .net packages in my code. my query look like this: ContactsQuery query = new ContactsQuery(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
query.NumberToRetrieve = 5000;
Feed<Contact> feed = cr.Get<Contact>(query); where here i can change the version? and i can see the birthday in : entry.ContactEntry.Birthday but cant seem to find the other info fields i stated elsewhere.

Comment: As long as in your 'url' request to google, it has,  ?v=3.0  OR,   &v=3.0     I'm not familiar with the .net setup for that. Google won't show empty fields in the feed, so make sure in your contacts the fields are filled in properly.

Comment: I was able to solve it like this, Anniversary is in the Events Collection.
the rest are or in the entry.ContactEntry or in the entry itself.
like entry.Content is the Notes.

    if(entry.ContactEntry.Events.Count > 0)
                            {
                                foreach(var a in entry.ContactEntry.Events)
                                {
                                    System.Console.Out.Write(a.Relation);
                                    System.Console.Out.Write(a.When.StartTime.ToShortDateString());
                                }
                            }